# repeatedly asking for user input until they enter "quit"

Tags: java

Why does the code break when the default case of the switch function is used.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
   static void checkCommand(String command)
   {
       switch (command) {
           case "add" -> System.out.println("added");
           case "access" -> System.out.println("accessed");
           case "compare" -> System.out.println("compared");
           default -> {
               System.out.println("Invalid command, please try again");
               enterCommand();
           }
       }
   }

   static void enterCommand(){
       System.out.print(">>> ");
       Scanner usrInput = new Scanner(System.in);
       String input = usrInput.nextLine();
       while (!input.equals("quit")){
           checkCommand(input);
           System.out.print(">>> ");
           input = usrInput.nextLine();
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       enterCommand();
   }
}
```

When I enter in "add", "compare", or "access", and then "quit", the program works as intended, but if I enter in anything that is incorrect where it uses the default case, the program breaks and repeatedly asks for input even if the input is "quit". I have tried a few different things to fix it and nothing has worked. I'm trying to keep the switch statement but if there isn't a way to keep it and have the program run as intended I am open to other options.

Comment: I’d consider using a do-while loop, as you need to do least one iteration of the loop anyway, this way you avoid prompting the user twice

Comment: By the way, don't open new Scanner(System.in) more than once. Put `static Scanner input;` under public class Main {. Then, open it before `enterCommand();` in the main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works for me. The only problem is that I have to enter *quit* twice, after entering an invalid command, in order for the program to terminate.

Here is output from a sample run of the exact same code as in your question:

```
>>> access
accessed
>>> add
added
>>> george
Invalid command, please try again
>>> compare
compared
>>> quit
>>> quit
```

I am required to enter *quit* twice because method `enterCommand` is being called from method `checkCommand`. You don't need to do this. The `while` loop, in method `enterCommand` will ensure that the user is prompted again to enter a command – even after [s]he has entered an invalid command.

Calling `enterCommand` from `checkCommand` means that you are essentially calling `enterCommand` recursively. In the above output, I needed to enter *quit* twice, since I only entered a single, invalid command. I suggest that you run your code in a debugger to understand why you get this behavior.

As @OldDogProgrammer wrote in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74697269/repeatedly-asking-for-user-input-until-they-enter-quit#comment131839139_74697269) to your question, you should create a `Scanner` object only once rather than each time method `enterCommand` executes.

As @MadProgrammer wrote in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74697269/repeatedly-asking-for-user-input-until-they-enter-quit#comment131838892_74697269), a `do-while` loop may be more appropriate than a plain `while` loop.

Also, *quit* is **not** an invalid command so I think that you need to handle that command in method `checkCommand` and the handling is that you just ignore the command. Since you are using [switch expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/switch-expressions.html), I couldn't find a way to "ignore" a case so in the below code I simply print an empty string. Alternatively, you could print an appropriate message such as *Good bye*, for example.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static Scanner usrInput;

    static void checkCommand(String command) {
        switch (command) {
            case "add" -> System.out.println("added");
            case "access" -> System.out.println("accessed");
            case "compare" -> System.out.println("compared");
            case "quit" -> System.out.print("");
            default -> {
                System.out.println("Invalid command, please try again");
            }
        }
    }

    static void enterCommand() {
        String input;
        do {
            System.out.print(">>> ");
            input = usrInput.nextLine();
            checkCommand(input);
        } while (!input.equals("quit"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        usrInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        enterCommand();
    }
}
```

Here is the output when I ran the above code:

```
>>> access
accessed
>>> add
added
>>> George
Invalid command, please try again
>>> compare
compared
>>> quit
```

As you can see, I only need to enter *quit* once.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand the recursive mechanism.
When the latest recursive has done, it needs to do the remaining tasks from previous recursive. I added comments into your code to explain:

```
    static void checkCommand(String command){
            switch (command) {
                // ... 
                default: {
                    System.out.println("Invalid command, please try again");
                    enterCommand(); // recursive is calling here.
                }
            }
   }
   static void enterCommand(){
           System.out.print(">>> ");
           Scanner usrInput = new Scanner(System.in);
           String input = usrInput.nextLine();  // time 1: input: test  | time 2: input: quit -> done recursive 1.
           while (!input.equals("quit")){
               checkCommand(input);             // time 1: go to default and call recursive, go to input time 2
               System.out.print(">>> ");        // Do the remaining task from time 1. In case you input time 3: "quit". the program will exit.
               input = usrInput.nextLine();
           }
  }
```

The more recursives are called, the more remain tasks need to do. In your code, to quit the program, you need to **type "quit" *(n + 1)* times** if the **recursive is called *n* times**

**Solutions**: To quit immediately after typing "quit" in the first time, just **remove the recursive call**.

```
default: {
       System.out.println("Invalid command, please try again");
}
```